# can i set up a reverse DNS to a public IP?

Tags: reverse-dns, isp

Is it possible to set up a "fake" reverse DNS to my internet public ip?
I don't want to buy a fixed IP address from the ISP and have them set up rDNS for me, I need to change my public ip more frequently than the billing cycle of the fixed one, and I need my ips to have revese DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. It is the ISP that controls the reverse DNS records. You *might* get a **custom** reverse DNS record for your static IP, but not for a dynamic one. Also, practically no ISP will allow fake hostnames there, but they typically test that the `PTR` record has a corresponding `A` record before changing it.